# 555 delay timer before powering PCB with 5 V

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, 555, delay

I am wanting to know if the circuit below looks correct for using a 555 delay timer to take ~5 secs before applying 5 V to the rest of the board? I'm not sure if I have the correct wiring for it to not power the board until the ~5 secs are up?

The 5 V IN is from my [K7805JT-500R3](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/mornsun-america-llc/K7805JT-500R3/13168096) that's converting 12 V to 5 V.

From the K7805JT-500R3 its sent to the pins 8, 4 and then through a resistor of 51 k to ground.

From the ground of the 51 k resistor it's connected to pins 2 and 6 and also the 100 µF 16 V diode all connected to the ground.

Once the ~5 secs is up it sends the 5 V through pin 8. **<--(this is the step I'm not sure about)** Should pin 8 not be connected to 5 V IN? Or should it be connected and some where else needs to have the 5 V OUT?

[image]

When I tested this in the [Tinkercad Circuit simulator](https://www.tinkercad.com/things/6Sii0WKUru4-555-delayer/editel?sharecode=zgp8h0H05XwUuO2yWWSZlBSrM8Q039AtCOurEVEKEPE) it seems to work just fine when following its schematic:

[image]

Comment: There are dedicated ICs for this purpose. Do a Digi-Key search for "Soft-Start" or "Power-Sequencer". They have all the functionality required, are commonly cheap, easy to implement and reliable.

Comment: This circuit makes no sense at all. Nothing is delayed here, both "5v in" and "5v out" are directly connected, always. Whatever the 555 does is completely irrelevant.

Comment: yeah @MarcusMüller it didn't look correct to me either. But that's the whole reason for my question :)

Comment: Yeah I'm really confused how to help you here. It's like you don't understand what it means to connect two nodes in a schematic. But explaining that together with explaining how to build a pet sequencer is just too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how a 555 timer works at all. Your description of the circuit is incorrect and the circuit itself is incorrect.

- The 51K resistor does not go to ground as you say, it goes to the trigger and threshold pins.
- The 100\$\mu F\$ part is a capacitor, not a diode.
- The timer does not 'send 5 V through pin 8'. Pin 8 is the supply pin,
  it is where the 555 gets it's power to operate, it is not an output.
- Pin 3 is the output, you have it conected to ground. This will not work.
- The output of a 555 is not going to provide much current (the [TLC555](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc555.pdf) version will source 15mA max), usually you would use it to drive a transistor switch to power something else.

There is a wealth of information on 555 circuits out there, it's not hard to find how to wire them properly. General rule of thumb, look for tutorials that use schematics rather than drawings.

There are a number of ways to make a power on timer, it can be done with a 555 but there are also power management ICs (PMICs) that are designed specifically to manage turn on times so you could look into those as well as doing some research on 555 circuits.

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge there! Would you be able to recommend a 555 ic that can do 180ma? I was unable to find any that went that high. I'm just powering a Wemos D1 mini (ESP8266) with the 5v along with a few leds.

Comment: @StealthRT then why the delay if you already have a microcontroller in the system? That makes no sense! Simply let the microcontroller wait five seconds before it starts doing its thing

Comment: Yeah i supposes i could just do that. Just thought a hardware way would be better.